# hatch and scripts entry point in Python

Tags: python, program-entry-point, hatch

I need a script to be produced by installing the package and to be put in user `PATH`. I've followed the [Hatch guide on entry points](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/metadata/#entry-points) and my directory looks like this:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── modules.rst
│   ├── pylb.experiments.rst
│   └── pylb.rst
├── LICENSE.txt
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── pylb
│       ├── __about__.py
│       ├── experiments
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── sphinx.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── scripts
│           └── __init__.py
└── tests
    └── __init__.py
```

my `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```
[project.scripts]
pylbtestapp = "pylb.scripts:main"
```

and `src/pylb/scripts/__init__.py` is:

```py
def main():
    print("Hi There! This is pylb test app.")
```

But when I install the package with pip, it does not put the script as it should (I guess). What am I doing wrong? For more info the full repo is [here](https://github.com/lbraglia/pylb).

Comment: What exactly is not working? I cloned the repo in a venv and pip installed it, this exposed the entry point just fine on my system (Debian 11, python 3.11.2) However, the `pip install pylb` does not work. After some looking trough it, it is obvious why, as that installed a package with completely different sources than the one found in the question, which comments and a readme in mandarin.

Comment: @Egeau somehow, i don't know how, now it's working as intended. Thank you for testing.

Comment: puzzle solved... being late evening i was using `pip install --user pylb` instead of `pip install --user ./pylb`, so installing pypi's pylb, which is a different package ..